# What is the most elegant Ruby expression for comparing and selecting values from a 2D Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, coding-style, expression

I have some code that is chugging through a set of Rails Active Record models, and setting an attribute based on a related value from a 2D Array.

I am essentially setting a US State abbreviation code in a table of US States which was previously only storing the full names. A library of state names is being used to derive the abbreviations, and it contains a 2D Array with each sub-array having a full name, and an abbreviation (i.e., `[['New York', 'NY']['Pennsylvania', 'PA'][etc]]`). I compare the state name from each record in the database to each full text name in this Array, then grab the corresponding sibling Array cell when there is a match.

This code works fine, and produces the correct results, but its frumpy looking and not easily understood without reading many lines:

```
# For the following code, StatesWithNames is an Active Record model, which is
#  having a new column :code added to its table.
# Sates::USA represents a 2D Array as: [['StateName', 'NY']], and is used to 
#  populate the codes for StatesWithNames. 
# A comparison is made between StatesWithNames.name and the text name found in
#  States::USA, and if there is a match, the abbreviation from States::USA is
#  used
if StatesWithNames.any? 
  StatesWithNames.all.each do |named_state|
    if named_state.code.blank?
      States::USA.each do |s|
        if s[0] == named_state.name
          named_state.update_column(:code, s[1])
          break
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What is the most Ruby style way of expressing assignments with logic like this? I experimented with a few different procs / blocks, but arrived at even cludgier expressions, or incorrect results. Is there a more simple way to express this in fewer lines and/or `if-end` conditionals?

Comment: 4 points: 1) Ruby has no concept of '2D' or 'nD' arrays; 2) You may find it  convenient to use hashes with elements such as `"New York"=>"NY"` rather than `["New York", "NY"]`; 3) You can simplify part of your code to `States::USA.each {|s| break named_state.update_column(:code, s[1]) if s[0] == named_state.name}`. (See [Object#break](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-break).) 4) An example with the desired result would be helpful. Assign each input to a variable, so readers may refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: 5. You need a Rails or ActiveRecord tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, there is a few `if`s and checks, that are not needed.

Since it is Rails even though it does not state so in question's tags, you might want to use [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each), which is one of the most efficient way to iterate over a AR collection:

```
  StatesWithNames.find_each do |named_state|
    next unless named_state.code.blank?
    States::USA.each do |s|
      named_state.update_column(:code, s[1]) if s[0] == named_state.name       
    end
  end
```

Also be aware, that [`update_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21) bypasses any validations, and if you wish to keep your objects valid, stick to [`update!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21).
And last thing - wrap it all in [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), so if anything goes wrong all the way - it would rollback any changes.

```
    StatesWithNames.transaction do
      StatesWithNames.find_each do |named_state|
        next unless named_state.code.blank?
        States::USA.each do |s|
          named_state.update!(:code, s[1]) if s[0] == named_state.name       
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a different data structure for this.

With your existing 2D array, you can call `to_h` on it to get a `Hash` where

```
a = [['California', 'CA'], ['Oregon', 'OR']].to_h
=> { 'California' => 'CA', 'Oregon' => 'OR' }
```

Then in your code you can do

```
state_hash = States::USA.to_h

if StatesWithNames.any? 
  StatesWithNames.all.each do |named_state|
    if named_state.code.blank?
      abbreviation = state_hash[named_state.name]
      if !abbreviation.nil?
        named_state.update_column(:code, abbreviation)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Some would prefer `named_state.update_column(:code, abbreviation) unless abbreviation.nil?`.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you want to do is convert the lookup from an array of arrays to a hash.

```
state_hash = States::USA.to_h

if StatesWithNames.any?
  StatesWithNames.all.select{|state| state.code.blank?}.each do |named_state|
    named_state.update_column(:code, state_hash[named_state.name]) if state_hash[named_state.name]
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would this get downvoted? I've tested all of the submitted answers so far, and this one seems to be the simplest and most elegant to me. It produces the correct result.

Comment: @Todd I did not downvote, but I guess one reason is that is uses pure Ruby, which is extremely inefficient when it comes to AR, because it loads the whole table data prior any processing. It can easily lead to memory overload when it comes to big amount of data

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thanks, that makes sense. Fortunately, this is going inside of a migration, and there will only ever be 51 records, and the entire table will need to be selected anyway.

Comment: @Todd It does not make any difference whether it goes inside the migration or not - selecting the entire database can be done in few other ways, and using Ruby for that is a sin :) Just in case you will be sometime interested in AR optimization - in my answer I've given you few hints on that.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thanks, I see the light ;-)

Comment: @Todd IMO be careful putting data changes inside a migration, its usually considered bad practice. IMO you should do the data change in a temporary rake task. [more info](http://johnpwood.net/2015/03/02/migrating-data-rails-migrations-or-a-rake-task/)